# How do I keep the leading 0 from A1 using formula =left(A1,4)?

Tags: excel-formula

How do I keep the leading 0 from A1 using formula =left(A1,4)?

ex. I have 01234567 in cell A1.  I want the 1st 4 digits of that number to be placed in cell D1 (including the leading 0).

So it should look like  0123, not 1234.

I've used =left(A1,3) and it works, however; I'm working with a lot of data and changing 1 cell here and there would be a pain.

Comment: We'd have to see some sample data showing where it's not working. Based on what you've provided, it should already be working, assuming the number 01234567 is in the cell as text instead of as a number.

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that the number of digits (including leading zeroes) is fixed, then this should work (for a fixed field width of 8):

> =LEFT(TEXT(A1,"00000000"),4)

The number of zeroes in the second arg to TEXT is the field width.